# Automatically export image from ply files

Tags: meshlab

I would like to automatically export to png (or jpeg or whatever) rendering from ply files, in order to make a movie. I am guessing I should need to use meshlabserver for this, but I couldn't find how to do practically.

Thanks,

Serge

Comment: Meshlabserver won't be able to help here. It is unable to render models because it don't create a render context. I suggest to use blender or another render program for that.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually used the python package Vedo

```py
from vedo import *
cell = load("file_name.ply").computeNormals().lineWidth(0.01)
world = Box([0,0,0], 12, 4.8, 3.2).wireframe()
plt=show(world, cell, bg='gray',bg2='dark')
```